# File path requirements in VS debug output window for navigating to the code

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2012

There is a neat feature in VS that allows you to navigate to the line that has produced the debug output by double clicking on it. It has been covered in multiple questions here and I was happily using the feature until I had to refactor the project a lot to make it cross platform. The refactoring included stripping full file paths from the log messages just to make the lines shorter. However after this move the double click feature in the log does not seem to work any more. Another thing is that now the sources are not stored in the same directory as the projects (maybe this also has some impact when using only filenames in the log instead of a full path).

So the question is - does VS require a full path in the debug output window messages for the double click navigation to work or does a single file name work as well? If the latter is true, are there any requirements on the layout of the files relative to the solution for this to work?

To be more illustrative of the issue here are two screenshots of working and non working output.

This works:
[image]

This does not work:
[image]

By looking at the length of the relative paths in the working scenario I think it seems logical that I want to reduce them, however if there are no means of doing this and preserving the debug output navigation feature I'll have to leave the long ugly paths.

Comment: You can tell that it doesn't need the full path from your first screen-shot.  The path must be relative to your project's path.  Not normally much of a problem, best to not put library source code in awkward directories perhaps.

Comment: @HansPassant well what I meant was is the filename enough and VS can figure out where to go if the file is included in the project but apparently not and it needs to be given the full relative path, thanks. I mean VS could be able to figure it out without the path.